# Core Data managed objects in swift - is nil allowed?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I have created NSManagedObject subclasses for my model objects in swift.

Typically my pattern is to create an instance of an object and then set properties on it, then save.

The new objects have properties that are set to nil. They are not optionals, though. I thought in swift this wasn't allowed?

A lot of times I need to check for values, but if I try something like:

if (managedObject.property == nil) I crash.

Comment: Why aren't they optionals? It sounds like they should be.

Answer (score 7):

It seems Xcode doesn't automatically make managed vars optional when creating NSManagedObject subclasses. If the values are set as optional in the model, they should be optional in the subclass as well. (I set them as optional manually)

[image: Model screenshot]

```
class ClassWithOptionalName: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var name: String?

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is managedObject.property optional value?

```
class CustomManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var aProperty: String?
                                    ^
}
```